# How to go back to previous page without session expire error by IE

Tags: jsp, session, caching

I have seen lots of examplke of going back to previous page using back button but none has described how to avoid page expired error.

I have JSP page(b.jsp) with the following code to go back to the previous JSP page(a.jsp)

```
  <input type="button" name="cancel_button1" value="Cancel"            onclick="history.back()"></input>
```

but when i click on this button, instead of getting the previous JSP page I am shown this error

> Webpage has expired 
>          Most likely cause: •The local copy of this webpage is out of date, and the website requires that you download it again.

How do i avoid this error. I heard of Caching, but I have no idea where to put in the JSP page and how.
Any advice would be very helpful

Comment: You can get your answer [here](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided on given link.

http://forums.modx.com/thread/48212/solved-webpage-has-expired-issue

Use following code in your JSP

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
```